# Why use steam instead of alcohol in Army of Darkness?

Tags: army-of-darkness

I was channel surfing this week and caught a scene from [Army of Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_Darkness) where they are pulling the engine out of that 1973 Oldsmobile Delta 88.  I surfed on by as I have seen the movie more than once.  But a little later got thinking.

As I recall they swapped out the gasoline engine for a steam engine that they built on site. Gasoline engines generally will run fine on alcohol when the proof is high enough.  Just from a logistical prospective it would seem that building a still would be quicker and easier than building a steam engine from scratch and connecting it to the drive system of a 1973 automobile.

Other than "Hollywood" was there a good reason to go with steam over alcohol?

**Edit**
There are some good answers and comments here.  In this edit I am clarifying where the potential alcohol would be coming from.  All [Alcoholic beverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcoholic_beverage) contain [Ethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol), the substance that gets you drunk or powers an engine is the same regardless of it is beer, wine or whiskey.  Ethanol has a boiling point of 78.37 °C; 173.07 °F; this is well below the boiling point of water 100 °C; 212 °F; [Distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distillation) is the process heating to separate elements.  If you take 200 gallons of 5% alcohol beer or wine (readily available in all Mideval castles) and heat it, at 78.37 °C; 173.07 °F the ethanol will start to boil, but the water will not. The steam that rises is ethanol steam, if your heating container has a lid, with a pipe coming out, you have a [still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still), if the pipe is long enough to allow the ethanol to cool (*and condense*), then nearly pure ethanol will flow out of the pipe.  The 200 gallons (4 good size kegs) will yield 10 gallons of fuel alcohol. Creating fuel alcohol is a couple of hours work, the castle with out a few hundred gallons of beer or wine is a pretty sad place.

Comment: Are you suggesting that they'd have alcohol with high enough proof on-hand to effectively power their 'war machine'? Because that's a pretty big leap.

Comment: @Zibbobz "it would seem that building a still would be quicker and easier than building a steam engine from scratch "

Comment: Attempting to justify logic in a universe where hands go evil, get chopped off and are replaced by chainsaws may be a tad difficult.

Comment: There was a [book on steam](http://apocalypseontheset.com/?p=1363) in the trunk. Logic is not that far away in this universe.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - but is there enough time to build the still, make the mash, let it ferment and fuel the car?  Granted you could ask if there was realistically enough time to build a steam engine, but in-universe apparently there was....

Comment: I don't know if it's ever shown what sort of agriculture is available in the kingdom, I'm not very well versed in moonshine, but isn't it usually made from corn?  I suppose making vodka from potatoes would be possible, I do remember seeing raw potatoes in a cart in the background somewhere.

Comment: ever seen back to the future 3 where they blow out the intake manifold (I think thats what they said anyway)

Comment: @joshbirk & Monty129 There is no reason to start from scratch, both beer and wine are plentiful in the middle ages.  You need only distal the alcohol off from the beer and wine. Assuming an average 5% alcohol in the available supply, 20 gallons converts to 1 gallon of pure fuel alcohol.

Comment: Will a 1973 Oldsmobile's engine run on distilled alcohol **after a 50 meter drop from the sky**? I think that sufficiently explains why a new engine of some kind needed to be built.

Comment: @Damon, as I recall they only pulled the engine, if the transmission (*automatic?*) survived in universe, there is no reason to suspect the engine would not.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - I can update my answer if necessary, but it is not that simple.  You can't just dump 20 gallons of beer and filter/distill out the alcohol into 95% ethanol.

Comment: @joshbirk, you have a good answer.  I have edited my question to clarify how easy the alcohol is to get (*at least in my mind*). I thought this was more common knowledge than it seems to be.  I believe you are correct that without a book on making ethanol and converting the engine to run on it, the challenges may be to much in any universe. Additionally the [fuel line issues](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9108) may have been insurmountable. If Ash, knew how to make fuel alcohol he may have all so known the fuel lines could rot before the battle was over.

Comment: "The 200 gallons (4 good size kegs) will yield 10 gallons of fuel alcohol." - Only if you had the world's most efficient/powerful distilling process on the planet.  If you want pure ethanol, you don't start with beer/wine - it's going to take a lot longer with multiple distillations, you have to keep taking impurities/anything but ethanol out.  You are going to end up with something like bad/weak whiskey or brandy that won't work that well for combustion. There's a reason why whisky is made from barley, not beer, and it isn't just taste.

Comment: @joshbirk granted, I was trying to simplify.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - and you are technically correct, I just think you're discounting the multiple distillations it would take make even mead something an engine would burn.  And if you wanted to convert all 200 gallons at once, we're upping the time to create the initial still/distillery.  It could be done, but it is not a fast process.  Updated the answer with that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons:

**Because a steam engine is less time with the materials they have on hand**

and

**Because the engine block is converted into a whirling blade of death (possibly because the engine was already trashed)**

On the first part, Ash has on hand:

1. [A book on steam power](http://apocalypseontheset.com/?p=1363) (thank you, OP)
2. Access to a working forge and blacksmith
3. Plenty of wood materials

So metal, fire, wood, someone who can craft metal and a book on steam power.  He's got everything he needs for a steam engine.  You could argue the realism of course, but in-universe this more or less shown to be the case.

To use alcohol to run the car, Ash should have:

1. [A book on converting your car to use alcohol](http://journeytoforever.org/biofuel_library/ethanol_drane.html), the modifications aren't demanding but things like updating the carburetor is non-trivial and isn't something someone will just guess at.

At this point we have to assume that the fort does not have barrels of ethanol laying around.  It is extremely unlikely that they would, alcohol at the time was generally fermented whereas ethanol would be [distilled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distilled_beverage).  The booze they have laying around is probably wine and beer, possibly [Mead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mead).  It is nowhere the level of ABV and purity they'll need to run the Olds.

The only reason they might have ethanol laying around is if there is an alchemist on hand who was already tinkering with distilling.  There's no evidence that I can find of that in the movie.

So now we also need:

2. Some kind of a [still](http://homedistiller.org/equip/types), assuming one was not at the fort it will need to be crafted.  This probably about the same amount of time as building parts of the steam engine, but needs to be done before any alcohol can be distilled
3. [Raw materials like wheat or sugar](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/166115/distilled-spirit).  There might be a farm around, the hay we see in the movie will not cut it.  The wheat is going to have to be collected, etc., again before the distilling gets kicked off.  Sugar is a better bet, there is probably some around a fortification like this - but probably not in large quantities.
4. And finally, and this is the problem ... [time to ferment and distill](http://homedistiller.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11818).  You might be lucky to have hours, it usually takes days or weeks to ferment.  Course they don't care about taste, but fermenting a gas tank's worth of ethanol is time consuming.  And they have to do all these other steps first.

The reason why this will take so long is a catch-22.  If you start with just basic ingredients (let's say sugar and water) - you have to wait for the sugar to ferment before you have any ethanol to distill. You could, as the question suggests, start with something that has an existing level of ethanol - like the commonly found mead with ... say 10% ABV ... but now you have lot more impurities to deal with than just water.  So you've got a head start, but you also have more work (and will get less volume in return).  [Here's a summary](http://homedistiller.org/theory/theory):

> When you heat up a mixture of liquids, the more volitile components will tend to come off first. There is a bit of overlap (so it is never pure), but generally we can seperate the ethanol from the water and other impurities present. The more alcohol in the liquid, the more alcohol will be in the vapour, **so multiple distillations allow us** to increase the strength & purity right up to 96.5%

For fuel grade ethanol - you probably need at least 90%, and you would prefer 95%.  In this [modern day example](http://www.markcoatsworth.com/blog/make-your-own-e85-biofuel) it took six hours to produce *one liter* (that's less than a quarter gallon) of ethanol that was pure enough ... and that is using ideal ingredients.  So even if we skip the fermenting step, you probably look at least 8-12 hours to distill.

And if the still explodes, they are just doing the deadites job for them.  So instead of waiting for ethanol, Ash and the blacksmith get to work.  And in the process, they...

[image]

...totally rip apart the car.  What used to house the engine block, where that carburetor  thing would have been important, now looks to have the gears to turn the whirling fan of death.  The actual engine is actually now behind Ash:

[image]

So it seems in order to make the DeathCoaster deadly enough, they are probably taking out most of the important parts to keep a combustion engine running.  Course this part of the answer may be causal - they created the whirling blade of death because they were putting a steam engine in the trunk.  But without that whirling blade of death, Ash's Deathcoaster strategy would have been much less effective.

And they also may have done this because the original engine was trashed anyway.  We don't know the specifics of the damage done - but if the carburetor cracked in the drop, it probably doesn't matter how high grade your ethanol is...

It's a solid question - but I think it would take an alternate setup where Ash had different books, and access to an alchemist as well as a blacksmith.  In this case the alchemist probably would have already something approaching ethanol laying around.

Comment: Other than the time/difficulty required to create fuel grade ethanol I agree with your answer. I posted an edit to my question, and added a comment on the sister site question identifying some of the other issues.

Answer (score 3):

Would be happy to be corrected here, but as memory serves, you can run an engine on alcohol if you make some conversions. Otherwise, the alcohol burns too damned hot and screws up the engine, dangerously so.

Also, I defy anyone to prove that an alcohol powered engine is cooler than a steam engine. And many things in the Evil Dead series were done for the sake of being cool.

Edit: I believe TVTropes would call this the Rule of Cool.

Comment: Posted related question at sister site [Will a 1973 Oldsmobile Delta 88 reliably run on home distilled alcohol?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9108)

Comment: Again, something I seem to recall hearing years ago was that rather than running on ethanol, it was more viable to change a car to run on methanol. Not sure of the veracity of this.